# Indentation in tcolorbox with plain theorem style

Tags: tcolorbox

Could someone tell me how to get proper indentation in my tcolorbox environment (created with `newtcbtheorem`)? I got from other questions that we can use `before upper`, but apparently when using `newtcbtheorem` and a `plain` style this is not helpful as `before upper` already contains the label, which is erased by the added code. I've seen in the doc that there are related options such as `before upper app`, but I don't see how to use that properly (and configure it only once for all the document).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[most,theorems,skins,listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  proofstyleone/.style={
    theorem style=plain,
    coltitle=black,
  },
  proofstyletwo/.style={
    theorem style=plain,
    coltitle=black,
    before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar{}},
  }
}
\newtcbtheorem[]{tcbproofone}{Proof}{proofstyleone}{p}
\newtcbtheorem[]{tcbprooftwo}{Proof}{proofstyletwo}{p}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbproofone*}{}
This is a paragraph to test.

There should be an indent here.
\end{tcbproofone*}

\begin{tcbprooftwo*}{}
This is a paragraph to test.

There should be an indent here.
\end{tcbprooftwo*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a sketch about what indentation do you want? A `1em` indentation before the first paragraph starting with "Proof: "?

Comment: Try `before upper app={\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}`?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I just noticed it does work on the MWE. But I tried that on my full document and I get ` Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/before upper app', to which you passed […]`. Not sure where the difference lies between the two documents.

Comment: `before upper app` is provided by library `hooks` of `tcolorbox` package. In your MWE, it is loaded by package option `most`.

Comment: Right, I got it working, thank you. So `before upper app` was the correct option, but I misinterpreted the error message (I thought I just could not use this option with `\newtcbtheorem`, but of course if it was not loaded this explains everything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments, with `tcolorbox` library `hooks` loaded, setting

```
before upper app={\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
```

is sufficient.